# How to produce quadruple density wavelet coefficients?

Tags: matlab, object-detection, wavelet, haar-wavelet

I refer to [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3703226_Pedestrian_detection_using_wavelet_templates), second-page right-column second-paragraph, where it is stated how to produce quadruple density wavelet coefficients:

> if we do not down sample the wavelet coefficients we generate
>       wavelets with double density, where wavelets of level n are centered every 1/2*2^n. To generate the quadruple density dictionary,we compute the scaling coefficients with double density by not down sampling
>       them. The next step is to calculate double density wavelet coefficients on the two sets of scaling coefficients - even
>       and odd - separately.

I am confused how to get `two sets of scaling coefficients - even and odd`. What does it mean by `even and odd`?

Is that like, split the original image matrix into two matrices with those only even-index (0,0) (0,2)..... and odd-index (0,1),(0,3)...? What is the advantage?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Those who has interest for Overcomplete Wavelet Transform, please look at these two links.

http://www.dahlsys.com/cuda/overcomplete_wavelet/index.html

http://eeweb.poly.edu/~onur/source.html

Thanks